# How to get data from firebase document to store it and use it in another method

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I've searched a lot on internet but i could not find the exact answer i need.

After implementing this method to get data from firestore from a specific document where username="dotcom"

```
  public void UserData(){
        db.setFirestoreSettings(settings);
        CollectionReference peopleRef = db.collection("member");
        peopleRef.whereEqualTo("Username", "dotcom")
                .get()
                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                    DocumentSnapshot document;
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            for (DocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                                Log.d("TAG", document.getId() + " => " + document.getData());

                            }

                        } else {
                            Log.d("TAG", "Error getting documents: ", task.getException());
                        }
                    }

                });
    }
```

i need the value of document.getData() to use it in another method inside the same class.
I've tested local and global variables with setters and getters, it won't work for me :(

Answer (score 0):

As clarified in this other post from the Community - accessible [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53056139/accessing-data-within-an-inner-function-in-java-with-firebase-firestore) - there are a couple of actions that you might take to achieve this goal.

To summarize, all of them involve you getting your data and setting it to an `ArrayList` that you can manipulate and use it outside the method. Within this `ArrayList`, there are two possibilities as well: the use of the asynchronous method `onComplete()` - more information in the official documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/tasks/OnCompleteListener) - where you will be able to get the data once it's completed; and the other way is to use the `toObject()` to add the objects to the array.

Both of them have some benefits in relation to the other - for example, using the `toObject()` you will have better management over the methods while they are being called and the other `onComplete()` will require less implementation.

Anyway, I would recommend you to take a look at the Community [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53056139/accessing-data-within-an-inner-function-in-java-with-firebase-firestore) to get more information and code samples for your own usage.

Let me know if the information helped you!

Comment: thanks for sharing the stackoverflow link, it's very helpful. I've applied List<Myclass> list = new ArrayList<>(); before the for loop and list.add(new Membre(document.getData())); inside the for loop, and when i print the value of list i got  [com.choubapp.app.Myclass@ae3ccd4] ? i have no idea how will i work with list

Comment: Hi @choub to use `ArrayList`, I would recommend you to take a look at the official Android documentation [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/ArrayList), on how to work with lists.