# Querying data from Firestore to Arraylist but got nothing?

Tags: java, android, firebase, arraylist, google-cloud-firestore

I have trouble adding data in ArrayList.
I tried to add data in array list but got nothing

Here's my code

```
public class fmMain extends Fragment {
     private ArrayList<markerList> posList = new ArrayList<markerList>();
public fmMain() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, final ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {


    //Firebase get data
    stores.get().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(QuerySnapshot queryDocumentSnapshots) {
            for (QueryDocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot: queryDocumentSnapshots){
                markerList m = new markerList(documentSnapshot.getId());
                posList.add(m);
            }
            Log.d(TAG,posList.toString()); //got value
        }
    });
    Log.d(TAG,posList.toString()); //got nothing     
}
```

as you can see when I tried to add value in function onSuccess I got value that has been added but when I tried to add outside function I got nothing

And here is my database structure
[image]

Comment: Hi Supagon! Please add your database structure as a screenshot and how your `stores` reference is defined.

Comment: Okay I edited my post now you can see my database structure below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot simply use the `posList` list outside the `onSuccess()` method because it will always be `empty` due the asynchronous behaviour of this method. This means that by the time you are trying to print `posList.toString()` outside that method, the data hasn't finished loading yet from the database and that's why is not accessible. A quick solve for this problem would be to use the list only inside the `onSuccess()` method, as in the following lines of code:

```
stores.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            List<GeoPoint> list = new ArrayList<>();
            for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                list.add(document.getGeoPoint("position"));
            }

            //Do what you need to do with your list
        }
    }
});
```

If you want to use that list outside this method, I recommend you see my anwser from this **[post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50650224/wait-until-firestore-data-is-retrieved-to-launch-an-activity/50680352)** where I have explained how you can solve this using a custom callback. You can also take a look at this **[video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0ofkvm97i0s)** for a better understanding.

Comment: Seem like you save me again thank you very much Alex for new knowledge I've never know

Answer (score 2):

You are getting this error because you are mixing asynchronous calls with synchronous ones. The `onSuccess` method (Asynchronous) will be called when you receive the data successfully from Firebase. But the onCreateView method will not wait for that. It will directly go to the second

`Log.d(TAG,posList.toString()); //got nothing`

and you will get nothing (actually I think you'll get an empty string) because you haven't received the data yet.

Comment: That's right!!, I miss my 2 days because of this thank you a lot