# Array List automatically clearing after storing information from Firestore

Tags: java, android-studio, google-cloud-firestore

So when I log the results of array.size during the database query, it shows the correct size (At this moment it should be size = 2). After the methods are called and the following line Throws an index out of bounds exception, invalid index 0, size is 0:

`currentVehicle = dataVehicles.get(vehicleSelectorAdapter.getVehicleCurrentPos());`

Am I missing something where the ArrayList is being cleared?

**On Create Method**

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_virtual_garage);

        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
        vehicleInformation = new ArrayList<String>();

        dataVehicles = new ArrayList<Vehicle>();
        getVehicles();

        vehicleSelectorView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.virtualGarageSelector);
        vehicleSelectorLayout = new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
        vehicleSelectorView.setLayoutManager(vehicleSelectorLayout);
        vehicleSelectorAdapter = new VehicleAdapter(dataVehicles);
        vehicleSelectorView.setAdapter(vehicleSelectorAdapter);

        currentVehicle = dataVehicles.get(vehicleSelectorAdapter.getVehicleCurrentPos());
        Log.d("d", "VIN: "+currentVehicle.getVin());
```

**Query to the Firestore DB**

```
 public void getVehicles()
    {
        CollectionReference vehicleRef = db.collection("Vehicles");

        Query query = null;
        if(lastQueriedDocument != null)
        {
            query = vehicleRef.whereEqualTo("userID", FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid()).startAfter(lastQueriedDocument);
        } else {
            query = vehicleRef.whereEqualTo("userID", FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid());
        }


        query.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                if(task.isSuccessful())
                {
                    for(QueryDocumentSnapshot document: task.getResult())
                    {
                        Vehicle vehicle = document.toObject(Vehicle.class);
                        dataVehicles.add(vehicle);
                        Log.d("d", "Vehicle Added, Array size = "+dataVehicles.size());
                    }

                    if(task.getResult().size() != 0)
                    {
                        lastQueriedDocument = task.getResult().getDocuments().get(task.getResult().size()-1);
                    }
                    vehicleSelectorAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    Log.d("d", "Vehicle Added, Array size = "+dataVehicles.size());
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

EDIT: The following article resolved my issues:

[Wait until Firestore data is retrieved to launch an activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50650224/wait-until-firestore-data-is-retrieved-to-launch-an-activity)

Thank you all for the help and direction!

Comment: `getVehicles();` is asynchronous  `dataVehicles` will not be populated until after `addOnCompleteListener` has been called

Comment: Where it is, is maybe OK, but maybe move `currentVehicle = dataVehicles.get(vehicleSelectorAdapter.getVehicleCurrentPos());` to within `addOnCompleteListener`

Comment: Ive done both of those and I'm still getting the same errors

Comment: after doing what Scary Wombat said you need to set adapter to recyclerview in the addOnComleteListener only other the other will be empty

Comment: Please check the duplicates to see why do you have this behavior and how can you solve this using a custom callback.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is related with variable scope:

`dataVehicles` declared inside of `onCreate` method is not available outside the method. Maybe it's enough to remove this declaration...

As you do not have errors in `getVehicles()` method you probably have global variable `dataVehicles` as well and you are shadowing it in `onCreate`.

I found nice article about it [here point 6.](https://www.baeldung.com/java-variable-scope)

I hope it will help!